# Ryzen-based platform for productivity

Tags: ssd, pcie

I am kind of lost when it comes to the "Pro" segment of system building, and I have trouble choosing a suitable platform, specially when everytime I search for something I get bombarded with gaming buzzwords and gaming "gear" everywhere.

The required configuration I have in mind includes:

- 3xNVMe SSDs vía a PCIe x16 card (like the ASUS Hyper M.2 x16 card), but I want to use the drives individually, not in RAID
- A regular SATA III spinning hard drive
- An x16 graphics card

Extended configuration (supporting this isn't a must, but it would be great for the long run):

- An USB 3.1 PCIe card
- A 10Gbit ethernet card

I don't care much about memory, so anything that supports DDR4 at 2400 is ok.

What Ryzen CPU+mobo would support such configuration?

My main drive is Linux and I plan to use Windows via KVM+Qemu with PCI passthrough, so anything that helps virtualization (VT-d/x) is also welcome, if that matters

Comment: What are you doing with this system? What's the budget? Do you specifically want Ryzen, or would another platform be okay? Would you be okay with used components?

Comment: I code and usually have 2 or 3 AVDs running along with docker, intellij, chrome with 20+ tabs, so I think I'd definitely benefit from multiple cores. The emphasis on the multi m.2 drives is because my workflow involves a lot of small I/O and I plan to run both OSs and /home from them (I can give up on one m.2 for windows though). I have been suggested threadripper instead of ryzen but it's a big step in cost, my budget is around ~$750 for the mobo, ram, cpu and at least 1 small m.2 drive)

Comment: What about used gear? Do you game at all? I'm thinking maybe a dual socket 1366 or 2011 system (especially given current DDR4 prices), but you'll probably be giving up a significant amount of single core performance in return for more cores.

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid used parts and intel altogether, given its small amount of PCI lanes, and new workstation hardware (xeon) is costly too. I do game but very little, if it can do 50-60 fps I'm good.

Comment: Gotcha. Used Intel would have plenty of lanes for relatively cheap, but I understand.

Comment: Do you absolutely need the GPU running at 16x or can it run at 8x (fine for gaming, other stuff might vary)?

Comment: I might even drop my current 1050 into a PCIe 2.0 8x, my priority is fast I/O hence my interest in nvme

Comment: What games and at what resolution are you playing?